# external stylesheet all css import between style tag in nodejs and then remove all stylesheet from html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I just want to just bring the external css file in between the style tag in nodejs
like

```
    <html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
     </head>
    <body>
   </body>
  </html>
```

to converted into

```
   <html>
    <head>
   <style>
   #p{
     "background-color": "red"
    }
   </style>
  </head>
   <body>
  </body>
   </html>
```

style.css file contain

```
#p{
"background-color": "red"
}
```

do this thing in nodejs and want to save to database